# Powershell to insert PFX into IIS, SmartCard Prompt Issue

Tags: powershell, smartcard, pfx

I have a PFX that I am trying to insert via Powershell.

```
Import-PfxCertificate –FilePath $certPath -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $securePassword
```

I use the `Import-PfxCertificate` cmdlet in powershell, it works, except that it prompts me about SmartCard when I do it.  I press cancel on the smart card prompt and all goes well.  I can't seem to suppress or get around it.  I am just trying to import to cert:\LocalMachine\My, nothing crazy.

I can replicate the prompt by going to the PFX, right clicking and install PFX.  After going through the wizard, if I choose Allow Windows to choose store, I will get the Prompt, if I choose the store manually I will not.  I would assume me setting the cert path in the powershell script would have the same effect, but I have not gotten around it.  I am wondering if I generated the pfx in such a way it feels it is smart card related.

SmartCard services are disabled on the machine which makes this that much more interesting.  Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and, for me, it was due to an incorrectly exported certificate from a machine.  The certificate was missing the private key or maybe just in some incorrect format.

I fixed this by using the following code to export the certificate and the new one worked fine.
https://github.com/OBeautifulCode/OBeautifulCode.Security/blob/master/OBeautifulCode.Security/CertHelper.cs

Method: ExportPfxFromCertificateStoreToFile